# Why aren't the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges paired together on the badge page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, badges

I earned the [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) badge earlier today, which prompted me to

- read over the [badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) in the Help Center and see what else I might be close to earning
- get confused about the [Suffrage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage) badge I already have
- read a dozen meta posts on why we have both Vox Populi and the Suffrage badge

While I was on the badge page, though, I noted that even though both the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges are rewarding similar behavior at different levels, they're not grouped together the way related badges normally are.

[image]

**Should the two badges be paired together?** The same shot shows the Tag Editor and Research Assistant badges in their own section, since they are rewarding the same activity (editing tag wikis).  Yet for some reason, the two badges that reward voting are separated.

The only reason I can come up with is that they're edge cases due to both being the same level - normal badge groupings reward behaviors with progressively harder-to-reach badges, from bronze up to gold, so perhaps the badge 'groupings' are defined as sets of bronze/silver/gold?

Is there any reason that these cannot or should not be paired together?

Comment: @HansPassant, I thought the list was alphabetical by lowest badge (e.g., if a bronze/silver/gold group is identified, the group gets positioned in the badge list at the alphabetical position of the bronze badge).

Comment: So they're sorted by badge creation rather than when you obtained it or alphabetically? (in other words, default sort?) I would at least do alphabetical so it seems to atleast have some order.

Comment: Reading the Moderation badge list by order of the first element in the group, you get Citizen / Civic / Cleanup / Constable / Critic / Custodian / Disciplined / Editor / etc...

Comment: Ah, so it is, somewhat alphabetic, by group. I see what you're saying now.

Comment: Both badges kind of useless IMO. Once someone wants one, they just randomly vote some posts without reading and then returning back to their normal voting behavior. Instead, Down voting/Delete voting/Dupes closing/OT questions closing should be rewarded **regularly** if we really want to encourage moderation on this site.